# TypeError: Can not read property 'map' of undefined. in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs. i have created my first application using react-app command. Now i am trying to call an RESTFUL API using 'fetch'. But i am getting the typeerror. Below are my code. Please help me to correct this,

```
var App = React.createClass({

 getInitialState: function() {
return {
  customerCollection: []
}
 },

  componentDidMount: function() {

// Is there a React-y way to avoid rebinding `this`? fat arrow?
 var th = this;

   var myRequest = new Request("/API/V1/Service.svc/customer/customernumber/1?format=json");
   fetch(myRequest)      
    .then(function(result) {
      if(result.ok) {alert(result.status);}
      th.setState({            
        customerCollection: result.data
      });
    })
    .catch(function(result){
      alert(result);
    })

 },

 componentWillUnmount: function() {
   this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

 render: function() {
   return (
      <div>
       {this.state.customerCollection.map(function(job) {
      return (
        <div>
          <a >
            {job.AdditionalInformation}                
          </a>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
  )
  }
   });

 ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,  
  document.getElementById('root')
   );
```

Comment: is `result.data` an array? I would double check that.

Comment: @denvaar its a json response like below,

"TotalCount":1,"customerCollection":[{"AdditionalInformation":.............something like this

Comment: you should change it to `response.data.customerCollection`

Comment: I did the same but no luck... actually just before posting this question i did the same... please help me out

Comment: Well, the issue is that this.state.customerCollection is being changed from an array to something else. I would console.log(typeof(response.data)) and console.log(typeof(response.data.customerCollection)) to see what it's being set as. Or if you have the react dev tools, you can just look at the state of your component.

Comment: I also just noticed that your updating the state even if the result of your fetch query is not `ok`.

Comment: in result.ok block i am getting 200 status... as you can see i have printed if(result.ok) {alert(result.status);}

Comment: after implementation of console.log(typeof(response.data)) and console.log(typeof(response.data.customerCollection)) i am getting same error.TypeError: Can not read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: and when you comment your fetch your component works correctly?

Comment: @kejt if i was using public api(Which is available over internet "http://codepen.io/jobs.json") it works correctly..not sure what is the error.. i was using this public api few days back.

Comment: can you show us your json here?

Comment: response is similar like https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json